# How to approach debug and fix of graphics system failure after update (nvidia340 driver, 20.04)

Tags: graphics, display, update-manager, gpu-driver, nouveau

Last night I allowed one of my laptops to do a reboot after an update, and the graphics system failed such that I never get a graphical login screen. Login still worked on the text consoles, however, for other reasons I was already planning to rebuild that machine, and have started to do so, thinking that would be the end of it.

However, just now I allowed another 20.04 machine (a desktop, so different video hardware-though perhaps using the same driver. also, a machine I'm reluctant to rebuild) and I'm faced with a low resolution login screen, and when I login it pauses, then dumps me back to that login screen (yes, I did type my password correctly, if I don't it tells me so, and this does not).

If I change to an xfce (am I remembering that correctly) login, I can get in, but it remains in very low resolution (I think, but haven't determined for sure, that it's 1024x768, whatever it is, it's a 4:3 aspect ratio).

So, I need to fix this one. Can someone tell me how I should go about this? I assume step one will be to look for info in the logs. Which logs, and what am I looking for? Then I suppose I might need to revert the updates, or replace something, but I expect I wait 'till I know what's wrong first?

Edit: I don't know how to find the "additional drivers" feature in xfce, but I have this additional info on the driver:

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:26:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000A65sv000019DAsd00001044bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GT218 [GeForce 210]
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

It has been suggested that I should use the "recommended tested" driver instead of nvidia-340, but this output seems to suggest that this is in fact the recommended (if not tested!)
More edit:

I worked out that the driver xserver-xorg-video-nouveau is supposedly available as an open source alternative, but I have not been able to persuade it to install. The gui rejects my attempts:

[image]

And if also fails if I try from a command line:

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
No drivers found for installation.
```

Why is nouveau both available and not at the same time?

Any suggestions would be very gratefully received. I'll add general info and logs as requested below.

Cheers,
Toby

General info:
(ancient) video card (clipped from output of lspci):

26:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 210] (rev a2)
26:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)

$ xrandr -display :0
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1024x768      76.00*

$ ubuntu-drivers list
nvidia-340

I notice that the drivers list in the laptop includes this nvidia-340 driver (though there are a couple of additional nvidia ones listed in that machine too).

Comment: You might try the "recommended tested" driver in your list.  340 is pretty old, and probably has been superdceded .

Comment: I've updated the question in response to this, can you add anything more in light of my edits?

Comment: Ah, found it. nv-340 is the "proprietary tested" but I'm going to try the open source version. I don't really care about performance, so it's gotta be worth a try.